# Remove fixed variable from quadratic program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a convex quadratic optimization problem with $n+1$ variables $x_i$

$$\text{minimize}\,f(x)=x^Tc+\frac{1}{2}x^TQx$$
$$s.t.$$
$$Ax=a$$
$$Bx\leq b$$

with exactly two equality constraints 
$$x_1=-1$$
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}x_i=1$$
and inequality constraints all being of the form
$$l_i\leq x_i\leq u_i$$
for potentially all $i\neq 1$. I.e. we have that $x_1$ is a fixed variable which does not occur in any other constraint.

From computation it looks like the problem can be reduced by completely removing $x_1$ and all corresponding elements in $c$ and $Q$, namely $c_1$, $Q_{1\cdot}$ and $Q_{\cdot 1}$.

**My question is**: Is it indeed correct that the above problem is equivalent to a problem with everything related to $x_1$ being removed? Either a quick explanation or a link to some literature would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you were solving an ordinary system of equations and at some point deduced that $x_1=-1$ then you would substitute this value for $x_1$ in all other places. This situation is no different.

Comment: Note that $x_{1}$ appears in cross terms with $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$, etc.    You can't simply drop those terms since these do depend on the remaining variables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, eliminating fixed variables via substitution is a basic technique performed by a *presolver* that attempts to simplify the problem before the actual solve.